# Get device part of a file path within grub.cfg

Tags: grub, grub2

I'm writing a custom grub.cfg for a drive that can be used in different computers.
Depending on the computer I use it in, the device identifier may be different (going from hd0, to hd1 or hd2, depending on the other drives present).

The `${cmdpath}` gives me the correct grub.cfg location, so I'm basically trying to do `set root=${cmdpath}/../../`. But then, `ls /` returns in error with the message `error: disk '(hd1,gpt1)/EFI/BOOT/../../' not found.`

⇒ Is there's a way to get the `hd1` part out of `${cmdpath}=(hd1,gpt1)/EFI/BOOT` using grub.cfg commands?

*I know the* correct *way to solve the issue would be to use the `search` command. But to simplify deployment, I'm trying to have the exact same grub.cfg on multiple drives (so no `search.fs_uuid`), and there can two instances of the same drive format on the computer (so I can't rely on `search.fs_label` or `search.file`).*

Comment: Perhaps the only way to fulfill your needs is to avoid having to change `root` (i.e., use the same partition / value for `--boot-directory` and `--efi-directory` when `grub-install`, a.k.a. use the ESP for `/boot`).

Comment: @TomYan this is actually a multiboot project, so the root was dependent on the menu entry selected.
For now I found a workaround that involves testing `${cmdpath}` against `'(hd0,gpt1)/EFI/BOOT'`, `'(hd1,gpt1)/EFI/BOOT'`, `'(hd2,gpt1)/EFI/BOOT'`, ... and setting a `drivenum` variable accordingly. I can then `set root='(hd'${drivenum}',gptX)'` in each menu entry.

I'm not proud of it, but it works.

Comment: Btw it seems that you've asked the wrong question. Apparently you want to get `hd1` instead of `hd1,gpt1` out of `cmdpath`.

Comment: @TomYan you're right, i'll edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just notice that there is a [`regexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#regexp) command:

```
regexp -s 2:drive (.*)(hd[0-9]*)(.*) $cmdpath
```

Even this somehow seems to work:

```
regexp -s drive (hd[0-9]*).* $cmdpath
```

not sure if it's a bug that the `(` in `cmdpath` somehow gets ignored/stripped in this case though, so the first approach might be safer (EDIT: unless somehow the original `root` is not on the same *disk* as `cmdpath` is, you can use this approach on `root` instead; Apparently `()` gets stripped anyway when the `root` gains its value)

Btw while I haven't checked, I think when grub is installed to an MBR drive for BIOS (i.e., in which case `core.img` is embedded onto the post-MBR gap), `cmdpath` would probably be an `hdX`. It does seem unfortunate to me that with the case of GPT (EFI or not), the variable wasn't (re)defined to be the *disk* that `core.img` is on, and no new variable has been introduced for that either.

Comment: I totally forgot about the regexp function. Thank you.
I settled on `regexp -s drive (hd[0-9]+) $cmdpath`